# App crashes when in apple review but not on local development

Tags: ios, swift, crash

The app crashes when the Apple team reviews it but cannot reproduce the crash when on development.

I've tried running it in all possible simulators, also tried the Amazon AWS Device Farm and on 2 different real devices (iPad and iPhone).

It appears the DateFormater is unable to parse the date and returns nil, before this we've parsed some other fields, but no dates.

We think the format should be as specified (we can parse it on our devices) and we use the same account as the apple review team.

We have also tried switching the Calendars to non gregorian, which did not crash the app either.

The App crashes on the `self.modified = ...` row

From Event.swift ...

```swift
import SwiftyJSON
...
  required init(json: JSON) {
    self.id = json["tm_event_id"].int!;
    self.name = json["name"].string!;
    self.eventStatus = EventStatus.init(rawValue: json["event_status"].string!)!;
    self.modified = AppDelegate.formaterDatetime.date(from: json["modified"].string!)!;
    self.dateFrom = AppDelegate.formaterDate.date(from: json["date_from"].string!)!;
...
  }
```

From AppDelegate.swift ...

```swift
  static var formaterDatetime:DateFormatter {
    let f = DateFormatter();
    f.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    f.timeZone = dataTimeZone
    f.locale = Calendar.current.locale;
    return f;
  }
```

The backend response (based on our server logs)

```
[
  {
    "tm_event_id": 1082,
    "company_id": 16,
    "organization_id": 58,
    "org_user_id": 126,
    "org_location_id": 93,
    "name": "My Test",
    "date_from": "2019-03-25",
    "date_to": "2019-03-30",
    "week_ending": "2019-03-31",
    "placement_count": 6,
    "notes": "",
    "event_status": "private",
    "created": "2019-03-04 13:25:25",
    "modified": "2019-03-04 13:25:25",
    "subrequirements": [ ... ],
    "timesheets": [ ... ]
  }
```

The Crash Log

```
Crashed: com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos
0  YouRecruit Work Tracker        0x1028b9470 specialized Event.init(json:) (Event.swift:224)
1  YouRecruit Work Tracker        0x10286424c specialized static StorableItem.initStatic(json:) (Event.swift)
2  YouRecruit Work Tracker        0x102844b20 closure #3 in _TempManAPI.().init() (<compiler-generated>)
3  YouRecruit Work Tracker        0x102844c4c specialized thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed Entity<JSON>) -> (@owned [Event]?, @error @owned Error) (<compiler-generated>)
4  Siesta                         0x102e22a0c (Missing)
5  Siesta                         0x102e2250c (Missing)
6  Siesta                         0x102df4700 (Missing)
7  Siesta                         0x102df9c70 (Missing)
8  Siesta                         0x102df96fc (Missing)
9  Siesta                         0x102df163c (Missing)
10 Siesta                         0x102de9fbc (Missing)
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x222a44a38 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x222a457d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x2229f6160 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 680
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x2229f68d0 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 128
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x222c251b4 _pthread_wqthread + 464
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x222c27cd4 start_wqthread + 4
```

Any idea how to reproduce the crash on local dev or what can cause this crash?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but don't use `;` at the end of lines in Swift, this is not Objective-C. Moreover, you should use `Codable` to decode JSON and force-unwrapping values from JSON is a really bad idea. If that's the full stack-trace and your full `init(json:)`, the crash most probably comes from the force-unwrapping.

Comment: Have you tried a TestFlight build?

Comment: dont use force unwrap. this is not professional way of managing code. if you are submitting build to app store, make sure there is 0 force unwrap in code.

Comment: Why it would only crash when with Apple (at least twice) and the previous values were read correctly?

Comment: Maybe the app crashes, because they test it under various network conditions and the server returned different json format (or empty data), than expected. Or maybe some of integers were coded as string As others have suggested, do not use force unwrapping and in some cases it is good to use optional init() so you can handle bad json data. 

And as I see the dates, I would suggest you to use datetimes with timezones, because your users might be on various places in the world and their 5th april might be others 4th april.

Comment: Well i can see exactly what data was sent back to the app, also the app must have decoded the json successfully, as it would not process it otherwise (using Siesta for REST, which can't loop over something that is not there). I understand i have to rewrite it to not use force unwrap and thanks for the optional init

Comment: Remove all force unwrapping, replace them with "if let" statements and manage each of those cases individually, this will probably fix all your issues, also there is no need to use SwiftyJson anymore, you could just use Codable protocol and decodeIfPresent ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, 
Rewriting the app to remove all force unwraps fixed the crashes